# Setting NHibernate timeout value for implicit ToList() call

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have table with 6+ million rows and need to select.  When the this was ind development our dev database has thousands of records, not millions and the following was fine:

```
 var results = ( from e in DomainRepo where e.ESIID == esiId select e ).ToList();
```

So now that this is 6+ million this bombs with a timeout.  Is it possible to set the timeout on a LINQ call like this?  Or does this have to be at the HHib config?  In the other place I touch the data I'm using QBE without a timeout set because of the filtering being done, but this is a straight ID call which seems perfect for the above above, except for the timeout.

Thanks.

Comment: consider remove the tag fluent-nhibernate since this is nhibernate + linq2nh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to page the result instead of incresing the timeout, even if you need all the rows ( some batch processing ? ) use a Take /Skip approach would light the whole architecture.